# Repository visits in Dspace Solr statistics

Tags: solr, statistics, dspace

Exists a way to query dspace statistics core to count the Repository visits. I am not looking for visits to communities or collections, only to the repository.
I tried using type: 5, but there is no record with that type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The query `type:5` should return those records.

Comment: Not work for me, i try this: http://myrepository.url/solr/statistics/select?q=type%3A5&wt=json&indent=true and return : "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[] }}. Others types works: communities, collections, etc. I need other configuration for the repository statistics (type: 5) ? My Dspace version is 4.2